# How to get a specific text from a javascript code in selenium webdriver by xpath

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to get a specific line of text, the "URL" under the "clip:" of this code.

I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="player"]/script[2]/text()")).getText();
```

but it is getting the entire text. I only want to get the url. Is there any solution for this?.

```
<div id="player">     
<script type='text/javascript'>
    flowplayer("thisPlayer", {
        src: "http://example.com.swf",
                    scaling: 'orig',
        wmode: "opaque"
    },  {
        key: "some key",
        clip: {
            url: 'http://someurl/example.mp4',
                            scaling: 'fit',
                            autoPlay: false,
                            autoBuffering: true,            
            provider: 'lighttpd'
        },

         plugins: {
                            lighttpd: {
                url: "http://example.com/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-byterange-3.2.11.swf"
            }

        }
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could not get the url from xpath.

After you have the text, as you did, you should use a regexp to get your url.

Maybe something like this:

```
/url:\s+"([^"]+)"/
```

This will save the url on matches.

Here an example on how to integrate in your code:

```
// From your example
var scriptText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="player"]/script[2]/text()")).getText();

// run the regexp on the script text
var matches = scriptText.match(/url:\s+"([^"]+)"/);

// check if you found something
if (matches.length > 0) {
    var url = matches[1];
}
```